# The best way to store a lot of text in android

Tags: android

I wonder what is the best way to store a lot of text in android. I need to show this text as fast as possible in text view . App will have predefined texts.
Please suggest what is the best way to store text ? Or I shoud use strings.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

### Store data ? ... Can you explain your query by adding more detail on what you are trying to do ?

---

- You can show any size data in any view like `TextView` etc..
- If you want to store more data in your android application try using
  `SQLite`
- `Strings.xml` can be used as a reference to your strings so that that
  you can internationalize your application resources

***Hope it helps*** !.... *Revert back to be if you need any additional information*

Answer (score -1):

Use SQLite manager ! Download an add-on of mozilla firefox named SQLite manager.

If data has to be stored in a form of database then use SQlite database, you can query some text & get result(s) corresponding to that  !

While storing data in strings.xml you cannot do search query !